# LuaLaTeX adds spaces between glyphs of a font, while XeLaTeX does not

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, white-space

Using the [IM Fell Type Fonts](https://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/) I ran into a problem with my document: With these fonts, the generated pdf will have additional, superfluous spaces between glyphs when compiled with LuaLaTeX. (I also found I have to re-generate the font files using FontForge; I had an older file of the same font, FePIrm27C, for which I didn't have to re-generate the font file. It can still be found on an [archived version of the above website](https://web.archive.org/web/20090122211321/https://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/).) Compiling my MWE with XeLaTeX will give a pdf with the strings I expect. I'm currently using TeXlive2023, and updated all packages today.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{IMFePIrm29C.otf} % May require re-generating the font with FontForge
%\setmainfont{FePIrm27C.otf} % For a the archived version which requires less font magic
\begin{document}
    This is a minimal test. fi fi fi fififififi ſſ ſi ſm
\end{document}
```

The produced pdf will look the same, but the text encoded will not be: That the problem only exists between glyphs can be seen when copying the text of the pdf. Ligatures appear without the additional spaces:

> T h i s i s a m i n i m a l t e s t . fi fi fi fi fi fi fi fi ſſ ſi ſ m

Meanwhile, with XeLaTeX the string will be:

> This is a minimal test. fi fi fi fififififi ſſ ſi ſm

As I have been working with LuaLaTeX on several bigger projects now, I would prefer to keep using it. Similarly, I am quite fond of the font, and don't want to replace it. Is there a way to get rid of these spaces somehow? Less importantly, but out of curiosity: What is happening here?

Comment: I suspect that your regeneration is the culprit, because I get no additional space from a 2010 version of the fonts (I don't think there aren't more recent).

Comment: The problem exists (for me, anyway) with all versions of the font. It looks right, but there's the spaces you can see in the quote. Even in TeXstudio's viewer I can encounter this: "T h i s" is found with Ctrl-F, but "This" is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Thanks to Marcel for pointing out that my answer below is factually wrong (one can perhaps still use it as a kind of workaround, and I let it stand for completeness). I apologize for that.

All OTF (CFF) fonts on my system (except this one now) have "Units per em" set to 1000, and reading a bit here and there, that seems to be what most people use, but not, as Marcel kindly points out, limited by the font format.

Opening the font in FontForge, and regenerating, one gets indeed this warning:

[image: FF warns that unitsperem is 2048 and not 1000]

So even FontForge suggests that 1000 is used (maybe because other values have implied problems for viewers and printers).

Maybe there is indeed something to fix in (the font loader of) luatex, but in this case I would simply use the TTF instead.

**Old answer**

With your updated question, it seems that the problem is indeed there when copying and pasting (from most viewers I tried, but not all), but it seems not to be the fault of luatex.

The OTF font is broken.

The problem (or at least one) is that the OTF version is generated with an em size of 2048, while 1000 is and should be assumed for OTF fonts. You can open the OTF font in Fontforge, go to

```
Element -> Font info -> General
```

and change change Em Size from 2048 to 1000 and hit OK. (Keep Scale Outlines marked.)

Then the generated font seemed to work OK here, at least with your small test. You can also be amused that maybe the size of the font is different:

[image: new output]

Top is old OTF font, middle newly generated OTF font, and bottom the TTF font.

In fact, the font seems to be designed for TTF, so maybe the safest bet is to use those versions instead of the OTFs. If the font is still maintained, you might file a bug report.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does this mean that XeLaTeX is more robust when it comes to "broken" fonts, or is this specific to this issue with the Em Size?

Comment: I do not know what xetex does, but my guess is that they just assume all otf fonts to be on the 1000 scale rather than listening to the parameter.

Comment: The OTF is not broken, it just doesn't follow usual conventions. The OpenType specification which defines OTF fonts explicitly states "Set to a value from 16 to 16384. *Any value in this range is valid.*" and e.g. the CFF2 table spec makes pretty clear that this also applies to CFF fonts (which conventionally use 1000). XeLaTeX just passes this though, which is the expected thing to do. LuaTeX on the other hand rewrites such fonts to nominally use 1000 but uses tricks with the font size to avoid visual differences which is kind of a hack which only really works for visual output.

Comment: So in some way it is LuaTeX's fault that these fonts work weirdly in conforming viewers. On the other hand there are good reasons why LuaTeX behaves the way it does: Some PDF viewers (mostly printers IIRC) do not support fonts with other em sizes and print them in the wrong size. So preserving them as is (while valid) leads to PDF files which look very wrong in some broken PDF viewers, so LuaTeX instead decides to ensure that they look correct in all viewers while accepting that the non visual data is somewhat off.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks for pointing out my mistake!