# Why is this merriweather font PDF output in LuaLaTeX vs. XeLaTeX different?

Tags: xetex, luatex, pdf, merriweather

This is the MWE, using [`merriweather`](https://ctan.org/pkg/merriweather).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{merriweather}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Compiled separately with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, this yields a different PDF output. The LuaLaTeX output (first paragraph) looks fine:

[image]

But it is unsearchable. Marking the first lipsum sentence and copying it gives: »L o r e m
ip s u m
d o lo r s it a m e t, c o n s e c te tu e r a d ip is c in g e lit. «

XeLaTeX, on the other hand, is fine (»Lorem ipsum« is highlighted, as I used this as a search-item example in my PDF-reader.)

[image]

I would like to understand what’s going on here with LuaLaTeX, and to learn if there is a simple fix for this problem. I have never seen this behaviour before with other fonts.

Comment: I find the different linebreaking more interesting (it appears Lua can't find the hyphenation for latin).  Copy/paste is a hard problem, and I'm not surprised that two different ways of creating a pdf end up with two different ways to place the glyphs.

Comment: Does LuaLaTeX have something like microtype built in?  That might mean that each letter is positioned explicitly with an extra kern applied; although a kern is not a space, who knows how copy-and-paste from a pdf file might interpret it.

Comment: @Teepeemm luaTeX compilation spits out a specific warning to the terminal about this, with instructions to fix it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't think so. It's something about either the particular version of the font included in current TL or something about the opentype version of the font. If I just use `\setmainfont` without loading the package, a system copy of the font is used. This works fine with lua and is truetype. But the `merriweather` package specifies the `otf` extension, so then I get the opentype font supplied by TL and stuff breaks.

Comment: Could be a regression: TL has 2.100 versus system 2.009. Or could be a ttf/otf difference? Although my package claims it is using 2.100, too. So perhaps my system just got lucky.

Comment: It works with TL 2019 which is the last version of TL I have which used truetype rather than opentype fonts. If you have truetype Merriweather installed on your system, it's relatively easy to create a `merriweather-mod.sty` which loads the truetype versions. Alternatively, you can set the fonts up manually without loading the package. Again, you need the truetype versions installed for this to work. It may also depend on how TeX is configured to find fonts. On my system, it appears to prefer system to TL fonts. But you can also force it by specifying the `.ttf` extension using `fontspec`.

Comment: But the problem should obviously be reported if others confirm the issue. Perhaps @barbarabeeton knows where a bug report should be directed? I am not sure if the problem is in the font, luaTeX or `fontspec`. The font works fine with XeTeX. LuaTeX works fine with other opentype fonts. `fontspec` is presumably just the middle being. ...

Comment: The OTF has the non-standard 2000 units per em. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699885/52406). There should be an update of luatex that handles these non-standard fonts out soon (if not now). On my machine it works out OK also in luatex.

Comment: @cfr: Adding the .ttf-font is a quick fix, although the general problem remains. Would you like to add this as an answer, or shall I?

Comment: @mickep: That seems to be the root cause, I read the comment by Marcel Krüger which is plausible to me but I’m not sure now if this qualifies the problem to be filed as a bug-report. I have TL 2023 complete, do know which update it is?

Comment: Since I'd already created a modified package when testing, see below. But I think @mickep has the real answer here.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround until LuaTeX is updated, you can use the truetype versions of the font. Provided you have these installed on your system, the following package `merriweather-mod.sty` should provide the same functionality as the original, but using the truetype fonts to avoid the bug.

```
\ProvidesPackage{merriweather-mod}[%
   2023/11/08 (Kubo) Modified support for Merriweather(Sans) fonts for all LaTeX engines. ] 
% this file is a derived work under the terms of the LaTeX Project Public 
% License, being a modification of merriweather.sty 2022/09/20 (Bob Tennent)
% Changes: load truetype rather than opentype fonts to workaround 
% incompatibility with LuaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700598/)
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex,textcomp}

\newif\ifmerriweather@otf
\ifxetex
  \merriweather@otftrue
\else\ifluatex
  \merriweather@otftrue
\else  % [pdf]LaTeX
  \merriweather@otffalse
\fi\fi

\newcommand*{\Merriwthr@scale}{1}  % not adjustable
\newcommand*{\MerriwthrSans@scale}{1}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareOptionX{scaled}{\renewcommand*{\MerriwthrSans@scale}{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{scale}{\renewcommand*{\MerriwthrSans@scale}{#1}}

\newif\ifmerriweather@rm \merriweather@rmfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@sf \merriweather@sffalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@sfdefault \merriweather@sfdefaultfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@rmlight \merriweather@rmlightfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@sflight \merriweather@sflightfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@rmblack \merriweather@rmblackfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@sfblack \merriweather@sfblackfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@rmlining \merriweather@rmliningfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@rmtabular \merriweather@rmtabularfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@sflining \merriweather@sfliningfalse
\newif\ifmerriweather@sftabular \merriweather@sftabularfalse


\DeclareOptionX{sf}{\merriweather@sftrue}
\DeclareOptionX{rm}{\merriweather@rmtrue}
\DeclareOptionX{sfdefault}{\merriweather@sftrue\merriweather@sfdefaulttrue}
\DeclareOptionX{type1}{\merriweather@otffalse}
\DeclareOptionX{light}{\merriweather@rmlighttrue\merriweather@sflighttrue}
\DeclareOptionX{rmlight}{\merriweather@rmlighttrue}
\DeclareOptionX{sflight}{\merriweather@sflighttrue}
\DeclareOptionX{black}{\merriweather@rmblacktrue\merriweather@sfblacktrue}
\DeclareOptionX{rmblack}{\merriweather@rmblacktrue}
\DeclareOptionX{sfblack}{\merriweather@sfblacktrue}
\DeclareOptionX{rmlining}{\merriweather@rmliningtrue}
\DeclareOptionX{rmoldstyle}{\merriweather@rmliningfalse}
\DeclareOptionX{sflining}{\merriweather@sfliningtrue}
\DeclareOptionX{sfoldstyle}{\merriweather@sfliningfalse}
\DeclareOptionX{rmtabular}{\merriweather@rmtabulartrue}
\DeclareOptionX{rmproportional}{\merriweather@rmtabularfalse}
\DeclareOptionX{sftabular}{\merriweather@sftabulartrue}
\DeclareOptionX{sfproportional}{\merriweather@sftabularfalse}


\ProcessOptionsX\relax

\ifmerriweather@otf
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
\else
  \RequirePackage{fontenc,fontaxes}
\fi

\ifmerriweather@rm\else\ifmerriweather@sf\else
  \merriweather@rmtrue\merriweather@sftrue  % both false -> both true
\fi\fi

\ifmerriweather@otf
  \ifmerriweather@rmlining
    \def\merriweather@figurestyle{Lining}
  \else
    \def\merriweather@figurestyle{OldStyle} 
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@rmtabular
    \def\merriweather@figurealign{Monospaced} 
  \else
    \def\merriweather@figurealign{Proportional} 
  \fi

  \ifmerriweather@sflining
    \def\merriweathersans@figurestyle{Lining}
  \else
    \def\merriweathersans@figurestyle{OldStyle} 
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@sftabular
    \def\merriweathersans@figurealign{Monospaced} 
  \else
    \def\merriweathersans@figurealign{Proportional} 
  \fi

  \ifmerriweather@rmlight
    \def\merriweather@regularstyle{Light}
  \else
    \def\merriweather@regularstyle{Regular}
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@rmblack
    \def\merriweather@boldstyle{Black}
  \else
    \def\merriweather@boldstyle{Bold}
  \fi

  \ifmerriweather@sflight
    \def\merriweathersans@regularstyle{Light}
  \else
    \def\merriweathersans@regularstyle{Regular}
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@sfblack
    \def\merriweathersans@boldstyle{Black}
  \else
    \def\merriweathersans@boldstyle{Bold}
  \fi
    
\else % type1
  \ifmerriweather@rmlining
    \def\merriweather@figurestyle{LF}
  \else
    \def\merriweather@figurestyle{OsF}
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@rmtabular
    \def\merriweather@figurealign{T}
  \else
    \def\merriweather@figurealign{}
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@sflining
    \def\merriweathersans@figurestyle{LF}
  \else
    \def\merriweathersans@figurestyle{OsF}
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@sftabular
    \def\merriweathersans@figurealign{T}
  \else
    \def\merriweathersans@figurealign{}
  \fi

  \ifmerriweather@rmlight
    \def\mdseries@rm{light}
  \else
    \def\mdseries@rm{m}
  \fi
  \def\seriesdefault{\mdseries@rm}
  \ifmerriweather@rmblack
    \def\bfseries@rm{black}
  \else
    \def\bfseries@rm{b}
  \fi

  \ifmerriweather@sflight
    \def\mdseries@sf{light}
  \else
    \def\mdseries@sf{m}
  \fi
  \def\seriesdefault{\mdseries@sf}
  \ifmerriweather@sfblack
    \def\bfseries@sf{black}
  \else
    \def\bfseries@sf{b}
  \fi

\fi


% Set main and/or sans fonts:
\ifmerriweather@otf

  \defaultfontfeatures{
     Ligatures = TeX ,
     Extension = .ttf ,
  }
  \ifmerriweather@rm
    \ifmerriweather@rmlight
      \ifmerriweather@rmblack
        \setmainfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BlackItalic ]
            {Merriweather}
        \newfontfamily\merriweather
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BlackItalic ]
            {Merriweather}
      \else
        \setmainfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]
            {Merriweather}
        \newfontfamily\merriweather
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , ]
            {Merriweather}
      \fi
    \else
      \ifmerriweather@rmblack
        \setmainfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BlackItalic ]
            {Merriweather}
        \newfontfamily\merriweather
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BlackItalic ]
            {Merriweather}
      \else
        \setmainfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]
            {Merriweather}
        \newfontfamily\merriweather
            [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]
            {Merriweather}
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@sf
    \ifmerriweather@sflight
      \ifmerriweather@sfblack
        \setsansfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-UltraBoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
        \newfontfamily\merriweathersans
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-UltraBoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
      \else
        \setsansfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
        \newfontfamily\merriweathersans
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Light ,
              ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
      \fi
    \else
      \ifmerriweather@sfblack
        \setsansfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-UltraBoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
        \newfontfamily\merriweathersans
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Black , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-UltraBoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
      \else
        \setsansfont
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
        \newfontfamily\merriweathersans
            [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
              Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
              UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
              ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
              BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
              BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]  
            {MerriweatherSans}
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  % grab the \sfdefault in case it changes subsequently:
  \let\merriweathersffamily\sfdefault
  \ifmerriweather@sfdefault
     \renewcommand*\familydefault{\merriweathersffamily}
  \fi
  \newfontfamily\merriweatherlight
      [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
        UprightFont    = *-Light ,
        ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
        BoldFont       = *-Light , 
        BoldItalicFont = *-LightItalic ]
      {Merriweather}
  \newfontfamily\merriweathersanslight
      [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
        Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
        UprightFont    = *-Light ,
        ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic ,
        BoldFont       = *-Light ,
        BoldItalicFont = *-LightItalic ]  
      {MerriweatherSans}
  \newfontfamily\merriweatherblack
      [ Numbers = {\merriweather@figurealign,\merriweather@figurestyle},
        UprightFont    = *-Black ,
        ItalicFont     = *-BlackItalic ,
        BoldFont       = *-Black , 
        BoldItalicFont = *-BlackItalic ]
      {Merriweather}
  \newfontfamily\merriweathersansblack
      [ Numbers = {\merriweathersans@figurealign,\merriweathersans@figurestyle},
        Scale     = \MerriwthrSans@scale ,
        UprightFont    = *-Black ,
        ItalicFont     = *-UltraBoldItalic ,
        BoldFont       = *-Black ,
        BoldItalicFont = *-UltraBoldItalic ]  
      {MerriweatherSans}

\else % type1

  \ifmerriweather@rm
    \ifmerriweather@rmlight\def\mdseries@rm{l}\else\def\mdseries@rm{m}\fi
    \ifmerriweather@rmblack\def\bfseries@rm{eb}\else\def\bfseries@rm{b}\fi
  \else
    \def\mdseries@rm{m}\def\bfseries@rm{b}
  \fi
  \ifmerriweather@sf
    \ifmerriweather@sflight\def\mdseries@sf{l}\else\def\mdseries@sf{m}\fi
    \ifmerriweather@sfblack\def\bfseries@sf{eb}\else\def\bfseries@sf{b}\fi
  \else
    \def\mdseries@sf{m}\def\bfseries@sf{b}
  \fi



  \def\merriweatherfamily{Merriwthr-\merriweather@figurealign\merriweather@figurestyle}
  \def\merriweathersffamily{MerriwthrSans-\merriweathersans@figurealign\merriweathersans@figurestyle}

  \ifmerriweather@rm
    \renewcommand*\rmdefault{\merriweatherfamily}
  \fi

  \ifmerriweather@sf
    \renewcommand*\sfdefault{\merriweathersffamily}
  \fi

  \ifmerriweather@sfdefault
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\merriweathersffamily}
  \fi
  
  \renewcommand*\seriesdefault{\mdseries@rm}

  \newcommand*\merriweather{\fontfamily{\merriweatherfamily}\selectfont}
  \newcommand*\merriweathersans{\fontfamily{\merriweathersffamily}\selectfont}
  \newcommand*\merriweatherlight{\fontfamily{\merriweatherfamily}\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
  \newcommand*\merriweathersanslight{\fontfamily{\merriweathersffamily}\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
  \newcommand*\merriweatherblack{\fontfamily{\merriweatherfamily}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
  \newcommand*\merriweathersansblack{\fontfamily{\merriweathersffamily}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}


\fi

% turn off defaults in case other fonts are selected:
\ifmerriweather@otf
  \defaultfontfeatures{}
\fi

\endinput
```

Note that renaming is required under the terms of the licence, if the file is distributed, and is wise, even if it is not.